# Is it possible to get the name of IntegerChoices

Tags: python, django

I have `IntegerChoices` like this

```
class Action(models.IntegerChoices):

    SYSTEM_START = 1
    SYSTEM_STOP = 2
```

and model has this as the member

```
class ActionLog(BaseModel):
    log_action = m.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=Action.choices,null=False)

    def action_name(self):
        // can I get the name such as SYSTEM_START here?
```

then I want to return the readable name in `action_name` function of model.

Is it possible?? or I should not use `models.IntegerChoices?`

If so what should be used in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.get_log_action_display()` will give you the readable name. Substitute `log_action` for any model choice field to get the display name.

Comment: wow it works like a charm. Thank you very much, I should read the source of IntegerChoices.